# Get all tags from taggit

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-taggit

How to get all the (unique) tags from django-taggit? I would like to display all the tags in a side bar.
Currently I am able to get all the tags for a particular post, but now I need to get all the unique tags in the entire blog.

code in models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [`all()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.all) to get all the tags in your database:

```
from taggit.models import Tag
tags = Tag.objects.all()
```

If you need a complete solution, have a look at [`django-taggit-templatetags`](https://github.com/feuervogel/django-taggit-templatetags). It provides several [templatetags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/), including one for tag list, to expose various taggit APIs directly to templates.

Comment: Thanks. Should I add "tags=Tag.objects.all()" under Post? And how to display it?

Comment: Do you mean for one post i.e. post = Post.objects.get(pk=1)? Or all posts (Post.objects.all())?

Comment: @Vino No, you shouldn't add it to your `Post` model. Edit the current view where you want to display the sidebar and pass the tag list to your template. `Tag.objects.all()` is the standard way to retrieve objects through the Django ORM. Have a look to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects) for more details. If you need only the tag names, use a list comprehension: `tag_names = [tag.name for tag in Tag.objects.all()]`

Comment: @Skidoosh Not for one post. I need all the tags in the blog.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti Thanks. Right now I am using only generic views. I have not created any View. 'views.py' is empty. So should I create a new view? (I am a newbie).

Comment: @Vino No, you don't have to create a new view. You can follow [these instructions](https://github.com/feuervogel/django-taggit-templatetags#instructions) to display a tag list in any template you like.

Comment: Great! Done! I followed the instructions - installed django-taggit-templatetags and used it to display the tags! Thanks a lot @PaoloMoretti et al. I love this django community in stackoverflow :)

Comment: @PaoloMoretti I will also learn the other standard way soon (using views).  Thanks for sharing  :)

Answer (score 5):

The currently maintained fork supporting newer versions of django is:
https://github.com/fizista/django-taggit-templatetags2

django-taggit-templatetags has not been maintained for some years.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question...but I'm a Django newbie and found this question while looking for a way to fill an Ajax dropdown with all tag options. I figured out a way with `djangorestframework` and wanted to put a more complete solution here for others (OP would also be able to populate a sidebar with the response, or do anything else with it).

This adds an api endpoint `tag` so you can not only view them by navigating to `/tag/` but get a JSON response suitable for Ajax (ergo, this assumes you have `djangorestframework` installed and in use).

*serlializers.py*

```
from taggit.models import Tag
class MyTagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ['name', 'slug']
```

*views.py*

```
from taggit.models import Tag
class TagViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    Not using taggit_serializer.serializers.TaggitSerializer because that's for listing
    tags for an instance of a model
    """
    queryset = Tag.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = MyTagSerializer
```

*urls.py*

```
router.register(r'tag', TagViewSet)
```

And, if you need the ajax:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $.ajax({
      url : "/tag/",
      dataType: "json",
      type: 'GET'
    }).done(function(response){
      for (var i in response) {
        tagEntry = response[i];
        $('#tagdropdown').append($('<option>', {
            value: tagEntry.name,
            text: tagEntry.name
        }));
      }
    }).fail(function(response){
      console.log('failed!');
      console.log(response);
    });

});
```